# Using Qt creator, why can't my class header compile?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, smart-pointers

[image]

I wrote two class header files. Before the two headers were included, the project was built successfully. But after they were included in the main.cpp , as shown in the image attached, it was complained while building that

```
12:54:13: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
g++ -c -pipe -g -std=c++0x -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -I/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../CPP_Primer_ch2 -I. -o main.o ../CPP_Primer_ch2/main.cpp
In file included from ../CPP_Primer_ch2/wy_StrBlob.h:19:0,
             from ../CPP_Primer_ch2/main.cpp:9:
../CPP_Primer_ch2/wy_StrBlobPtr.h:30:30: error: expected ')' before '&' token
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
12:54:15: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project CPP_Primer_ch2 (kit: Desktop)
When executing step 'Make'
```

Below is the code of wy_StrBlobPtr.h to which `error: expected ')' before '&' token` was refering.

```
#ifndef WY_STRBLOBPTR_H
#define WY_STRBLOBPTR_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <wy_StrBlob.h>
#include <stdexcept>

class wy_StrBlobPtr
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<std::string> tp;

    wy_StrBlobPtr() : curr(0) {}

    wy_StrBlobPtr(wy_StrBlob &sb, std::size_t sz = 0) : wp(sb.data), curr(sz) {}
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

private:
    std::weak_ptr<tp> wp;
    std::size_t curr;
};

#endif // WY_STRBLOBPTR_H
```

What's the problem here?How to fix it?

**Update:codes of wy_StrBlob.h. Definitions for the members are omitted for simplicity. Please let me know , if they are needed.**

```
#ifndef WY_STRBLOB_H
#define WY_STRBLOB_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <wy_StrBlobPtr.h>

class wy_StrBlobPtr;

class wy_StrBlob
{
    friend class wy_StrBlobPtr;

public:
    typedef std::vector<std::string>::size_type size_type;

    wy_StrBlob() :
        data(std::make_shared<std::vector<std::string>>()) {}

    wy_StrBlob(std::initializer_list<std::string>   il) :
        data(std::make_shared<std::vector<std::string>>(il)) {}

    size_type size() const { return data->size(); }
    bool empty() const { return data->empty(); }

    //! add and remove
    void push_back(const std::string &s) { data->push_back(s);}
    void pop_back();

    //! elements access
    std::string& front();
    const std::string& front() const ;

    std::string& back();
    const std::string& back() const ;

    wy_StrBlobPtr begin();  //return wy_StrBlobPtr to the first element
    wy_StrBlobPtr end();    //return one past the last element

private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> data;
    //! throws msg if data[i] isn't valid
    void check(size_type i, const std::string &msg) const;
};
#endif // WY_STRBLOB_H
```

**Upadte 2nd:include guards are added.**

Comment: Could you show the declaration of `wy_StrBlob` please (contents of `wy_StrBlob.h` respectively)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ declaration of `wy_StrBlob` has been added.

Comment: No include guards, really??

Comment: You have a cyclic dependency. Remove #include <wy_StrBlobPtr.h> from wy_StrBlob.h.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There are include guards. I didn't paste them to make the codes shorter..

Comment: I think removing `#include <wy_StrBlobPtr.h>` should do the job. Didn't spot this immediately ...

Comment: @Alan.W Additionally do not inline any code referring to `wy_StrBlobPtr`, but move these to an extra compilation unit.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What do you mean by  do _not inline any code referring to wy_StrBlobPtr_? I'm a newbie..Could you explain more about it and make it more easily to understand?

Comment: @Alan.W _'What do you mean'_ Do not place such code in the header file but in the corresponding `.cpp`, you don't actually seem to hit this problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Can I sum up this way: I should use 4 files to store the two classes.`wy_StrBlob.h` and `wy_StrBlobPtr.h` are used for classes declarations which inline all codes inside the class body,`wy_StrBlob.cpp` and `wy_StrBlobPtr.cpp` for members definitions. Do you mean this?

Comment: @Alan.W As a rule of thumb yes! It will deviate when you're going to introduce template classes. But as long you're using simple class declarations/definitions follow that rule. You might want to inline stuff like getter/setter functions that do not depend to `wy_StrBlobPtr` in the header though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove

```
#include <wy_StrBlobPtr.h>
```

from `wy_StrBlob.h`

`class wy_StrBlobPtr` needs the definition of `wy_StrBlob` known, however by including the header file, `wy_StrBlobPtr` is being defined before `wy_StrBlob` symbol is known to the compiler.

Comment: I tried but didn't work..still complained the same thing `error: expected ')' before '&' `token.

Comment: I just tried your code without the include line, it compiles just fine.

Comment: Yes,you are right!! I had misunderstood your post and removed the forward declaration  class `wy_StrBlobPtr;` I'm so stupid..